# When waiting on a pagefault, in what kind of sleep is a task?

Tags: process, virtual-memory

Are tasks put into interruptible/uninterruptible/killable sleep when waiting on a pagefault? Does it matter, what kind of pagefault is it?

Comment: Can someone add a 'pagefault' tag to this?

Comment: Creating a new tag requires imho a stronger reason, but I extended the tagging.

Comment: I was thinking that 'pagefault' is a general enough topic to warrant a tag, regardless of this specific question.